# Iterating over a sorted hashtable with Select-String includes blank lines?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to extract certain values from a sorted hash table using `Select-String`.

This works, but why are there extra blank lines in the output?

```
cls

$fruits = @{"1" = "apple"; "2" = "lemon"; "3" = "orange"; "4" = "apricot"}

foreach ($fruit in $fruits.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value) {
    $fruit.Value | Select-String -pattern "ap" -SimpleMatch
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting the empty values because for each item you're doing a Select-String, which is returning a value sometimes but nothing at other times - those nothings are the blank lines.

Try something like this that uses Where-Object:

```
$fruits.Values | Sort-Object | Where-Object { $_ -match "ap" }
```

Comment: Interestingly, blank lines are only there if there is at least one match.

Comment: I think those may be the precontext and postcontext.

Comment: What's strange is that the blank lines appear even when all items in the array are matched, e.g. `$fruits = @{"1" = "apple"; "2" = "apricot"}`

Comment: @MrKWatkins Thanks for the `Where-Object` suggestion which works as expected; question now marked as answered. Still curious about those blank lines though. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PowerShell 3.0.

I did two lines of code

```
PS C:\> $fruits = @{"1" = "apple"; "2" = "lemon"; "3" = "orange"; "4" = "apricot"}
PS C:\> $fruits.Values -like 'ap*'
apricot
apple
PS C:\>
```

**Further Investigating**

Seems to be that when there is no match it returns NULL.

```
foreach($key in $fruits.Keys){(Select-String -Pattern 'ap' -SimpleMatch -InputObject $fruits[$key]) -eq $NULL}
```

Since it is not redirecting to a variable it just prints NULL to the Host. That's my assumption (assume).

Strange...good question.

Comment: Oops forgot to sort. `$fruits.Values -like 'ap*' | sort`